# Управление игрока волной, как в Geometry dash

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для моей игры нужно управление игрока волной, как в Geometry Dash. Но, я не знаю как это сделать. Если что волна нужна подобная :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: меняете знак у проекции скорости стрелки на ось y при зажатии

Comment: Ты пытался сделать с помощью формулы прямой y = kx + b, при нажатии клавиши менять знак

Comment: Вопрос интересный, жаль нет собственных попыток решения :(

Comment: Если вопрос решен, вы можете отметить ответ как решение, для этого нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще в GeometryDash это не основное управление, а лишь одно из множества дополнительных, но не важно...

---

#### Физика не подойдет

Насколько я помню в GD это движение не было физическим: смена направления происходила резко, то есть вряд ли получится реализовать это через изменение гравитации, так как тогда объект пойдет по параболе. Тогда можно сделать нефизическое движение.

### Вариант №1: Translate на вектор

Самое простое, что можно сделать:

```
    public Vector2 MovementDirection; // Направление движения
    public float Speed; // Скорость

    private void Start () {
        MovementDirection.Normalize(); // 1
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) 
            MovementDirection.y *= -1; // 2

        transform.Translate(MovementDirection.normalized * Speed * Time.deltaTime); // 3
    }
```

> // **1** — Нормализуем вектор, чтобы его длина была равна единице, и скорость передвижения задавалась исключительно переменной Speed
> // **2** — Изменяем направление, когда пробел нажали или отпустили.
> // **3** — Нефизическое передвижение. Домножаем на `Time.deltaTime`, чтобы избавиться от привязки к FPS.

В этом случае, чем больше будет координата `X` в `MovementDirection`, тем быстрее объект будет двигаться вправо, чем больше `Y`, тем быстрее будет двигаться вверх-вниз, и наоборот. Математическим языком, `выражение Y/X — тангенс угла наклона прямой полета`

***Обратите внимание***, что в этом случае, благодаря нормализации, постоянным остается модуль именно вектора **(общей) скорости**, а не проекции этого вектора на ось X.

### Вариант №2: Translate на угол

В этот раз будет использовать на вектор перемещения, а более понятную человеку характеристику — угол наклона.

```
    public float SlopeAngle; // Угол наклона
    public float Speed; // Скорость

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            SlopeAngle *= -1; // Меняем угол наклона на противоположный при нажатии/отжатии пробела

        Vector2 MovementVector = new Vector2(Speed, Speed * Mathf.Tan(SlopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        transform.Translate(MovementVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Важно домножить `SlopeAngle` на `Mathf.Deg2Rad`, чтобы перевести угол из *градусов* в *радианы*.

Само передвижение (последние две строки в `Update`) можно сделать немного по-другому:

```
Vector2 MovementVector = new Vector2(1, Mathf.Tan(SlopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
transform.Translate(MovementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Чтобы не обращаться дважды к переменной `Speed`, домножим вектор на нее уже при передвижении.

***Обратите внимание***, что в этом случае постоянной будет именно **проекция скорости на ось X**, то есть "скорость вправо" будет постоянна вне зависимости от угла наклона, в отличие от предыдущего варианта.

**Вы можете задавать угол не только в градусах**. Вот несколько модификация варианта №2:

```
1) public float SlopeAngleRad; // Угол в радианах
2) Vector2 MovementVector = new Vector2(1, Mathf.Tan(SlopeAngle));

1) public float TgSlopeAngle; // Тангенс угла наклона (во сколько раз передвижение по Y будет больше передвижения по X за единицу времени)
2) Vector2 MovementVector = new Vector2(1, TanSlopeAngle);

1) public float CtgSlopeAngle; // Котангенс угла наклона (во сколько раз передвижение по X будет больше передвижения по Y за единицу времени).
2) Vector2 MovementVector = new Vector2(CtgSlopeAngle, 1);
```

- Под `1)` указана переменная, контролирующая наклон, под `2)` — чему должен быть равен вектор движения `MovementVector` для получения желаемого поведения.
- Во всех трех модификациях предполагается, что домножение на скорость `Speed` производится непосредственно в `transform.Translate()`.
- Во всех трех модификациях варианта 2 постоянна именно ***проекция* скорости на ось X** вне зависимости от угла наклона.

Comment: Я попробую оба варианта. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я попробовал этот код реализовать. И у меня, в 2 он дрожал и не менял Rotation. Возможно это у меня проблемы или я, не правильно понял вас

Comment: @owinoob У меня все работало хорошо. Как сработал первый вариант? Какие вы задали значения переменным скорости и угла наклона во втором?

Comment: @owinoob Вы точно правильно записали условие в Update?

Comment: Не всё нормально работает. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @owinoob Не совсем вас понял, но хочу быть уверенным, что у вас все получилось. Что вы имели в виду: "**не всё** нормально работает" или "*[да] не*, *[уже]* **всё** нормально работает"?

Comment: Да, уже всё нормально работает

Comment: Здраствуйте, извините что только сейчас написал. Но вы знаете, как сделать так. Что бы, при нажатии и 
при отжатии Space. он также менял свою rotation. Например если двигается вверх, то и угол наклона был вверх на 30f. Как я понимаю, здесь нужно использовать Quaternion. Но я пробовал, и не получалось. Видно отжатие unity не видит

Comment: В Update проверяем нажатие/отжатие пробела: `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))` и `if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))`. Вращать можно так: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z)` где x, y, я - углы поворота по 3 осям. Т.к. у вас игра 2д, скорее всего нужно `(0, 0, 30)`

Comment: Это я пробовал. Он при управлении, смотрит только на вверх. А когда if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) он не смотрит вниз.

Comment: @owinoob Попробуйте скинуть в комментарии полный код вращения. Не вообще полный, а именно вращения. Попробую найти ошибку.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо за помощь!!!